# Не работает fs.readFileSync

Tags: javascript, node.js, require

Есть две разные ситуации с одним и тем же кодом

```
var fs = require("fs");
var content = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('./config.json', "utf8"));
```

Без проблем запускается на одном компьютере.

А на втором выкидывает ошибку:

> Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open './config.json'
>       at Object.openSync (fs.js:436:3)
>       at Object.readFileSync (fs.js:341:35)
>       at Object. (—)
>       at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:688:30)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:699:10)
>       at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:598:32)
>       at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:537:12)
>       at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:529:3)
>       at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:741:12)
>       at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:285:19)

Comment: а ОС на этих компьютерах разные?

Comment: Английским по белому написано, что нет такого файла. Проверяйте в какой папке происходит запуск, т.к. путь к файлу написан относительный

Comment: @Дмытрык я обновил вопрос

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Данная проблема решилась строками:

```
const config = path.join(__dirname, '/config.json');
const content = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(config, "utf8"));
```

Дело в точке, т.к. на разных системах это воспринимается по разному. 
В Node.js  ***__dirname***  всегда находит каталог, в котором находится текущий исполняемый скрипт. Так что, если вы ввели ***__dirname*** в ***/d1/d2/myscript.js***, то значение будет ***/d1/d2***.
В отличие ***.*** от этого, вы получаете каталог, с которого вы запускали node команду в окне терминала (т.е. в вашем рабочем каталоге).
Исключение при использовании ***.*** с ***require()***. Путь внутри require всегда относится к файлу, содержащему вызов require.

Помогла эта [статья](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8131344/what-is-the-difference-between-dirname-and-in-node-js): 
Но сразу после запуска следующая ошибка:

> Error: error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line
>
> ```
> at Object.createSecureContext (_tls_common.js:113:17)
> at Server (_tls_wrap.js:868:27)
> at new Server (https.js:62:14)
> at Object.createServer (https.js:84:10)
> at Object.<anonymous> (---)
> at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:688:30)
> at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:699:10)
> at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:598:32)
> at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:537:12)
> at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:529:3)
> ```

Однако, если указывать подобный образом, то всё работает и программа успешно запускается.

```
const conf = https.createServer({
  cert: /.../.../certificat.txt,
  key: /../../keys.txt
});
```

Comment: слушай, ты сейчас сделал 2 ошибки: написал низкокачественный ответ (не пояснил причину поведения программы, а лишь рецепт решения своей проблемы - снизив таким образом ценность этого ответа в базе знаний) и задал второй вопрос в ответе (а нужно было создать ещё один вопрос). хорошо бы исправить эти ошибки

Comment: а вообще тебе просто сообщают, что сертификат не корректный

Comment: @nörbörnën как смог, так и ответил. Если вам кажется неправильным это, пометьте вопрос флагом и я уберу ответ.

Comment: @nörbörnën если вернуться ко второму вопросу, то я упомяну, что если указывать абсолютный путь на сертификат, то всё запускается и успешно работает, т.е. сертификат корректный. Сейчас выше поправлю и приведу пример.

Comment: тебе, снова же, нужно указать путь к сертам от `__dirname` (ну, если они лежат в твоём проекте, иначе - абсолютный)